# How can I run JavaScript on a network computer remotely?

Tags: javascript, psexec, wscript.shell

I would like to remotely install IBM iAccess 1.1 on a network computer using PSexec to run the JS file. The problem with this is that the installation would be hung on *some* computers (wscript.exe would be stuck in Task Manager).

The installation file is a JS file "install_acs_64.js"

I also tried using..

```
cscript.exe /E:jscript \\server\folder\IBMiAccess_v1r1\Windows_Application\install_acs_64_allusers.js" /CQ"
```

instead of..

```
wscript.exe "\\server\folder\IBMiAccess_v1r1\Windows_Application\install_acs_64_allusers.js" /CQ
```

This is the code that the PSexec runs on the remote computer: (/CQ arg is to bypass EULA and Quiet install)

```
wscript.exe "\\server\folder\IBMiAccess_v1r1\Windows_Application\install_acs_64_allusers.js" /CQ
```

I expect the shortcuts would be created on the desktop to show finished installation.

Comment: did you try node install_acs_64.js?

Comment: Apologies, I had several tabs open and it appears that I've posted that reply to the wrong question.

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan I thought about that, but don't you need node.js to be installed on the remote machine first?

Comment: yes @Hexalogy you need to have node installed